# how to move a buttonView from its original position to the new position in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I have a button in (0,0) position when i click on that it should be moved to (-x,-y) position for ex (-0,-2) position OR (x,-y) position for ex (0,-2) position.How to implement this logic.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: what version of android u use?

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="10" 
android:targetSdkVersion="21"

Answer (score 2):

you can use translate animation for that

```
 Animation animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( this, R.anim.animation);
 button.startAnimation( animation);
```

create **amin** folder in **res**
and in amin folder create xml named as animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-60"
    android:toYDelta="-30" />
</set>
```

now you can play with translation

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
        float fromX=0;
        float toX=0;
        float fromY=40;
        float toY=40;
        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(fromX, toX, fromY, toY);
        animation.setDuration(300);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        yourView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 1):

If u use Android 3.0+

```
ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(yourButton, "x", newX);
animation.setDuration(animTime); //In milliseconds
animation.start();
```

if u dont use Android 3.0+ u cant use the library: http://nineoldandroids.com/
to backport this funcionality.

cheers